# How to extract words from comoblist with python?

Tags: python, format, extract

i have a combo list with this format:

Name:Age:City

The only thing i need is the City. But how do i extract this part with python?

Comment: What is a combo list? It is not a built-in Python type so if you're using some library you should mention that and post a ***[mre]***

Comment: share your combo list how it looks like..

Comment: It looks like a CSV with colons instead of commas. The `csv` module may help.

Comment: Were you the one who asked the exact same question a couple of hours ago with just one change instead of Name:Age:City it was username:password:token? [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275283/how-to-sort-words-in-txt-file-with-python/75275349#75275349)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList = ["Name:Age:City"][0].split(':')[-1]
```

Comment: The code myList = ["Name:Age:City"][0].split(':')[-1] will extract the last element from the string. And provide full code with example show usage of your code